# Android animation flies off the screen when setting the screen width

Tags: java, android, animation

I have an arrow image that is drawn on the screen (top left corner) and animates to the X most corner based on the screenwidth.

I know the screenwidth values are correct as I've got a ball that also bounces around the screen and can see it colliding with the screen edges.

However the arrow image that gets animated ignores the edge and carries on. From debugging it looks like the screen width (1440Px) is not correct for the animation.

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
    screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    ImageView arrowImageView = findViewById(R.id.arrowImageView);
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animator.setDuration(30000); 
    animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE); // Set repeatCount to INFINITE

    // Define the PropertyValuesHolder for X and Y
    float animstartX = 0; // Starting X position (left edge of the screen)
    float animendX = screenWidth; // Ending X position (right edge of the screen)

    PropertyValuesHolder xHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", animstartX, animendX);
    PropertyValuesHolder yHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", animstartY, animendY);

    // Add the PropertyValuesHolder to the animator
    animator.setValues(xHolder, yHolder);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float animatedValue = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            float newX = animstartX + (animendX - animstartX) * animatedValue;
            float newY = animstartY + (animendY - animstartY) * animatedValue;
            arrowImageView.setX(newX);
            arrowImageView.setY(newY);

            // Get the current animated values for X and Y
            float animcurrentX = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue("x");
            float animcurrentY = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue("y");

            // to do check current values for ball
            
        }
    });
  animator.start();`
```

`